# What is the difference between this two types of kernels?

Tags: image-processing, kernel, fft, convolution

Suppose, I have a Spatial kernel function `(, )`, and an image `(, )` of dimension x.

I want to apply this kernel to the image using  convolution.

Now, I can do two things from this point on:

1. i. Generate a small kernel of size `3`x`3` from the function `(, )`
   ii. Pad that kernel to the dimension of x
   iii. Convert them to matrices of complex numbers, apply FFT to both of them, multiply matrices, and so on.
2. i. Generate a big kernel of size  x from `(, )` so that **we don't do padding**
   ii. Convert them to matrices of complex numbers, apply FFT to both of them, multiply matrices, and so on.

Are they both valid / operations, or only #2 is valid?

**What is the difference between these two?**

Comment: Display the kernel from (1) after padding next to the kernel from (2). What are the differences? Those are the differences between the two linear filters you apply. If the difference is hard to see, their outputs will be similar and (1) will be a valid approximation to (2). If the differences are obvious, then these two filters will not be equivalent. It all depends on your function *f*, whether it extends significantly beyond the 3x3 window.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, `If the kernel is 3x3, computing by FFT is perfectly counterproductive.` --- Yes I know.